# Content of a variable is [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

**Problem**
I am creating a simple app using React Native and firebase where users can post to the web and see what other people have posted. You can upload things to the servers but when you try and render the posts using a flatlist, the posts say [object Undefined] instead of what is on the server. I would love help fixing this.

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API-key",
  authDomain: "candidtwo.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://candidtwo.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "candidtwo.appspot.com",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var fontLoaded = false;

var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts');

var newPostRef = ref.push();

var postWidth = 350;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };



  componentDidMount() {
      Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf': require('./JosefinSans-Regular.ttf'),
      });
 }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { postInput: ""}
 }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getItems();
 }

  getItems(){
    var items = [];
    var query = ref.orderByKey();
    query.once ('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach ( (child) => {
         items.push(child.val());
      });
    }).then(() => {
        this.setState({firebaseItems: items});
    });
 }


  renderItem({ items, index }) {
   return  <View>
                <View style={{width: 360, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight:10}}>
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        {/*{toString(reverse(items))}*/} {toString(items)}
                    </Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{width:360, height: 40, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#147aa8', flexDirection: 'row',paddingLeft:5}} >
                    <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/unlove.png')} />
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                        -
                    </Text>
                    <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/undislike.png')} />
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                        -
                    </Text>
                    <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/comments.png')} />
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                        -
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
            </View>;
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
            title="Get started anonymously!"
            color="#fe8200"
            accessibilityLabel="Run the app"
          />
        </View>

        {this.state.fontLoaded ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Whats on your mind? Create a post!
            </Text>  

            <TextInput
                 style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                 onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
                 value={this.state.postInput}    
             />


    <Button
      style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}
      onPress={() => {
        newPostRef.set({ content:this.state.postInput });
        this.setState({ postInput: "Your post was succsesfully uploaded! :)" })    
      }}               
      title="   +   "
      color="#fe8200"
    />

            <ScrollView>

<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Adjust the size of posts:
            </Text>  

            <TextInput
                 style={{height:40, width: 100, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                 onChangeText={(postWidth)=>this.setState({postWidth})}
                 value={this.state.postWidth}    
             />



               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: parseInt(this.state.postWidth), height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',    borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight:10}} >
         <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    Why do android phones have higher inital quality than apple phones, but apple phones have a more consistent amount of quality throughout their years?
                </Text>
            </View>
               <View style={{width: parseInt(this.state.postWidth), height: 40, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#147aa8', flexDirection: 'row',paddingLeft:5}} >
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/unlove.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                    3
                    </Text>
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/undislike.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                    1
                    </Text>
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/comments.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                    8
                    </Text>
        </View>
    <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />


     <FlatList
        data = {this.state.firebaseItems}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
    />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>) : (null) }
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
});
```

**Firebase database layout**

```
posts:
  ipaurfiauerspfna(random example key):
    content: "hello world"
  apiergnfpiarngaenig:
    content: "test"
```

**helpful warning message**[![warning][2]][2] VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a random key property on every item or provide a custom keyExtractor.

Comment: `the posts say [object Undefined]` which line **in your code** produces that output

Comment: @JaromandaX this.setState({firebaseItems: items});

Comment: @KenWhite my bad. I changed the second image to the warning. I think the first one could b helpful for getting content off of the servers.

Comment: @KenWhite Alright, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull `firebaseItems` from state before you have set it (due to the delay in query response), so this will throw an error. To fix this, declare it is a state variable in your constructor. EG

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
       postInput: "",
       firebaseItems: [],
    }
  }
```

Comment: PS i think i answered a question for you before ( I see some of my suggested code ), so if you are still having issues just comment on the OP instead of making a new one

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't set some variables yet, you are going to want to extend your current code of:

```
state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };
```

to

```
state = {
    postInput: "", // Or some other default
    fontLoaded: false,
  };
```